# LARGE function giving reapeted value

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, ms-office, formula

I'm having troubles when using `LARGE` function, that's why:

I have a list of different parts claimed by some clients, and there are different quantity depending of the part.

I'm using `LARGE` to make a top 5, but when there is a repeated value the function give this repeated value, even when I change the K of function.

I used the following function to avoid this:

```
=IF(LARGE($BL$69:$BL$109;2)=BM69;LARGE($BL$69:$BL$109;3);LARGE($BL$69:$BL$109;2))
```

Which helped in some cases, but it still happens,

Is there something I can do to always bring me a exclusive value? Like improving this function i did to always bring me a new value.

The only thing i can think is to make this `IF` embrance all the possibilities, but the function would be giant, and i don't know if this would be possible.

Comment: If you have Office 365 you can nest `UNIQUE()` around each array inside the `LARGE()` functions.

Comment: You might want to look [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/nth-largest-value-with-duplicates) for older versions of EXCEL.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot(s) refer:

```
=LARGE(UNIQUE(C4:C21),SEQUENCE(F3,1,1,1))
```

[image: Top 6 illustration]

*(assumes you have Office 365 compatible version of Excel)*

Comment: Kudos to @bugdrown for being first to jump straight to what effectively represents the foundation of my proposal in intiials comments RE Q.